# Can't auto copy the mouse selection

Tags: vim, macvim

https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Auto_copy_the_mouse_selection

I put this in my `~/.vimrc` and my `~/.gvimrc`.

```
 set guioptions-=a
 set guioptions-=A
 set guioptions-=aA
```

Completely closed and reopened macvim and still, when selecting text with the mouse it is automatically copied. I don't want mouse select to copy at all.

Comment: `A` and `a` are not part of the default value of `:help 'guioptions'` so… a) MacVim doesn't copy text on selection unless you tell it to, by purposely adding `a` to the default value and b) explicitly removing them in your `~/.vimrc` or `~/.gvimrc` seems rather pointless. Remove or comment out those three lines, save your config files, quit MacVim with Cmd+Q, start MacVim again, and run the following command to know the current value of the option and where it was last set and report back with its output: `:verbose set guioptions?`.

Comment: Hi red888. Please use a spelling checker when posting here. This is not a discussion forum or a chatroom where you "own" posts - we want good posts to live forever here, and to be useful to many future readers. To that end, we ask contributors to make an effort when they post.